# Change HTML content with PHP, Xpath and / or DOM

Tags: php, html, xslt, dom, xpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xPath insert before and after - With DOM and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660962/xpath-insert-before-and-after-with-dom-and-php)

I need to parse HTML code within a string, in a good nice correct way.

Wordpress creates a sidebar with a structure that looks like this.

```
<div class="sidebar-1">
   <ul>
      <li id="archives">
          <h4>Archives</h4>
          <ul>
             <li>a href="">Test1</a></li>
             <li>a href="">Test2</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="pages">
          <h4>Archives</h4>
          <ul>
             <li>a href="">Test</a></li>
             <li>a href="">Test</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

**I want to create a <div class="content"> after </h4> and a </div> before the </li> the parent element, in both list sections "archives" and "pages". It should work if more unknown list items are added.**

The result should be like this:

```
<div class="sidebar-1">
   <ul>
      <li id="archives">
          <h4>Archives</h4>
          <div class="content">
             <ul>
                <li>a href="">Test1</a></li>
                <li>a href="">Test2</a></li>
             </ul>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li id="pages">
          <h4>Archives</h4>
          <div class="content">
             <ul>
                <li>a href="">Test</a></li>
                <li>a href="">Test</a></li>
             </ul>
          </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

I tried to make a DOM-function but I did not figure out what needs to be done and how to do it. It returns the content within the h4-tags in a array. Not very helpful.

```
    function add_sidebar_content($html)
    {
       $dom = new DOMDocument();
       $dom->loadHTML($html);
       $xpath = new DomXPath($dom); 
       $tag = $dom->getElementsByTagName("h4");
       $counter = $tag->length;
       for ($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++)
       {
          $result = $tag->item($i)->nodeValue;
       }
       return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and for a solution in which the language that hosts XPath is XSLT.

Comment: umm, it's been a while since I worked on WP but isn't this a theme related issue?

Comment: Yes, it's a theme related question but the Wordpress theme system is very flexible and accepts PHP functions to solve problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is in this thread [xPath insert before and after - With DOM and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660962/xpath-insert-before-and-after-with-dom-and-php)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a hook to do this instead of trying to modify the content after-the-fact. I'm not sure which hook you'd use offhand, but [you can find all the hooks available here](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/).

Comment: Thanks for that additional information. It does not solve the problem but can be useful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**XPath is the query language for XML and as such cannot modify an XML document**.

In order to modify an XML document one needs to use the programming language (such as XSLT, C#, JS, PHP, ..., etc) that is hosting XPath.

**Here is a solution, where the hosting language is XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "li/ul[preceding-sibling::*[1]
         [self::h4 and .='Archives']
       ]">
  <div class="content">
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed):

```
<div class="sidebar-1">
    <ul>
        <li id="archives">
            <h4>Archives</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Test1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Test2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="pages">
            <h4>Archives</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Test</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Test</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<div class="sidebar-1">
   <ul>
      <li id="archives">
         <h4>Archives</h4>
         <div class="content">
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <a href="">Test1</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="">Test2</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li id="pages">
         <h4>Archives</h4>
         <div class="content">
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <a href="">Test</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="">Test</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I use PHP and HTML, not XML and XSLT. Wordpress generates the HTML as a PHP string. I don't know if it's the way to solve this problem?

Comment: @Jens-Törnell: I can assure you that using XSLT for this problem or for any transformation of a tree-structured data is the way to go. XSLT is a language especially designed for tree-structured-data transformation and as such it is the most powerful in doing this. In XSLT you typically can specify a complex transformation just in a few lines -- that in other languages would require very challenging coding and would result in spaghetti-like ununderstandable code.

Comment: Interesting. XSLT is new to me. I searched the web and found this PHP code.

   $parser = xslt_create();
   $html = xslt_process($parser, "exampleDocument.xml",
           "exampleTemplate.xsl");
   xslt_free($parser);
   echo $html;

I guess I could build upon that but I have a PHP string, not an external XML document (which is needed by the example).

Comment: I don't know PHP. Most DOM implementations have a method like: `XmlDocument.LoadXml(someXmlString)`